# Does some event like Thread.OnAborting() exist?

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception

**Environment:**

Let's say I have a main application that:

- Listen for requests for tasks to do,
- Perform those tasks (that use some resources (in a physical meaning)) one after another,
- Must be able to *instantly* stop a pending task to dispose the resources.

I got two timers:

- On the `timer1` tick, the application is retrieving new requests and store them in a `Queue`,
- On the `timer2` tick, the application is dequeueing a request to perform the task in a new `Thread`.

When a user ask to stop all tasks to have the resources free, I plan to simply kill the thread running the current task with [`Thread.Abort()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty8d3wta.aspx).

**Problem:**

I would like to be able to save some last configuration when killing the thread from the thread class.

**Question:**

Is there a way to detect when the thread is killed, like a `Thread.OnAborting()` event?

Or maybe could I catch the [`ThreadAbortException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadabortexception.aspx) raised when calling the `Thread.Abort()` method? (if so, I don't really know how to do it, could you provide some code example?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Other than catching the `ThreadAbortException` no other mechanism exists. Of course, you really do not want to be calling `Thread.Abort` anyway because the `ThreadAbortException` gets injected asynchronously and those injections points can be unpredictable. For example, it could be in the middle of a write which might leave the entire AppDomain in a corrupted state. .NET 2.0 added [constrained execution regions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228973.aspx) which makes dealing with thread aborts a lot safer and easier to handle, but it is still *incredibly* difficult to author a block of code that can guarantee that the AppDomain will not get corrupted. My advice is to punt on the `Thread.Abort` idea.

Instead what you want to do is send a signal to the thread and allow it terminate gracefully on its own. This can be done with the following mechanisms.

- Poll a flag
- Use wait handles
- Call `Thread.Interrupt`
- Use the cancellation mechanisms built into the APIs of long running operations

You can see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632149/question-about-terminating-a-thread-cleanly-in-net/3632642#3632642) for more information.

Comment: I chose this answer as The Answer as it provides several ways to handle the end of a `Thread`. I'm gonna go with the "Poll a flag" solution. Nevertheless, solutions from _Emiswelt_ (provides a snippet) and from _Chris Shouts_ are worth taking a look at them.

Answer (score 1):

[How To Stop a Thread in .NET (and Why Thread.Abort is Evil)](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2004/11/12/cancellation)

Answer (score 1):

Leito, it will probably be the best way to design the tasks interruptable by simply settings a flag or issuing a event or signal. Sadly, you've provided to less details for me to provide you with an exact code snippet, but a possible, very basic, solution could be:

```
class MyTask
{
    bool bShouldDoWork;

    public event EventHandler Aborted;

    public void DoWork()
    {    
         bShouldDoWork = true;          

         while(bShouldDoWork)
         {
              //Do work.
              //But ensure that the loop condition is checked often enough to
              //allow a quick and graceful termination. 
         }

         if(Aborted != null)
         {
              //Fire event
              Aborted(this, EventArgs.Empty);
         }
    }

    //Call this method from another thread, for example
    //when a button is pressed in your UI etc.
    public void Abort()
    {
         bShouldDoWork = false;
    }
}
```

Please note that this snippet is very basic and might require modification to fit your needs. I hope it helps you to catch the idea of correct multi-threading.

Please do not use Thread.Abort(). It only will give you lots of headache.

Comment: Noted to not use `Thread.Abort` ;). I think I'll go with a boolean flag, it seems to me the solution that is the most adapted to my solution. Your code snippet is a good start, thanks for it. I just have a question on what is the use of the Aborted event?

Comment: You kind of asked for it ("Thread.OnAborting() event"), but just remove it, if you don't need it. 
Hope it works out for you. :)