# c# Console Application - Run for(;;) loop while not disturbing rest of executing code

Tags: c#, console-application

I have a C# console application that needs to call a function immediately when the application begins running, in this example `ExecuteForLoop();` .

This is how my C# console application starts running:

```
static void Main()
{
    ExecuteForLoop();
    Console.Write("Test");
}
```

the function `ExecuteForLoop()` in this example does this:

```
ExecuteForLoop()
{
    int example = 0;
    for(;;)
    {
        example++;
    }
}
```

The problem is that if I call the `ExecuteForLoop()` function the `Console.Write("Test");` function ***will*** not execute immediately. `"Test"` will ONLY be outputted to my console once the `for(;;)` loop within `ExecuteForLoop()` stops looping.

How can I call `ExecuteForLoop()` and continue executing code so the function `Console.Write("Test");` will be outputted to my C# console application while the `for(;;)` loop within the `ExecuteForLoop()` function is still running?

Comment: You'd need to use threads

Comment: Invest some time in studying parallel `Task`s and synchronization. This part is absolutely nesessary to know.

Comment: Formation of an infinite loop inside `ExecuteForLoop()` you need to specify some exit condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use multi-threading:

```
static void Main()
{
    var t = new Thread(() => ExecuteForLoop());
    t.Start();
    Console.Write("Test");
    t.Join() // See this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/14131739/4546874
}
```

Also, that might not exactly be what you want. Are you sure you need an *infinite* for-loop in the method? If not, see the syntax for a `for-loop` and set an exit condition accordingly.

`"Test"` is not printed because in the previous line you call the `ExecuteForLoop()` method, in which the program runs into an infinite loop. Since, both statements are in the same thread, the latter cannot be executed unless the previous is, which of course is impossible.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly :)

Answer (score 4):

You should almost never use `Thread` directly.

Use [Tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx) instead. They are a higher-level abstraction and are much easier to work with than threads.

A simple example:

```
var backgroundTask = Task.Run(() =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Background task started");
    while (true)
    {
        //do something
    }
});

Console.WriteLine("Back in main");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Another one, cancelling the task after a key is pressed and returning a result:

```
var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
var token = tokenSource.Token;
var backgroundTask = Task.Run(() =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Background task started");
    long count = 0;
    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        count++;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Background task cancelled");
    return count;
}, token);

Console.WriteLine("Back in main");
Console.ReadKey();
tokenSource.Cancel();
Console.WriteLine("Counter: {0}", backgroundTask.Result);
Console.ReadKey();
```

A great resource to learn more about tasks is [Stephen Cleary's blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/04/a-tour-of-task-part-0-overview.html).

Answer (score 2):

Create a `Thread` and run your logic inside

```
static void Main()
{

    Thread t = new Thread (ExecuteForLoop);          // Kick off a new thread
    t.Start();  

    Console.Write("Test");

    t.Join();  // wait for thread to exit.
}
```

I recommend reading [`Albahari`](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) articles/blog on threading, it is very detailed.