# How do I exit my thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

So I have made this thread to keep checking if a certain program is running which works just fine however when I try to end it by changing ThreadStatus to false it just keeps running.

```
    public bool ThreadStatus = true;

    public void Run()
    {
        while (ThreadStatus)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Process[] nProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);

            if (nProcess.Length > 0)
            {
                if (!nProcess[0].HasExited && ThreadStatus == true)
                {
                    nProcess[0].Kill();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void StartThread()
    {
        thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.Run));
        thread.Start();
    }
```

Comment: Let's switch optimization on `ThreadStatus` off: `public volatile bool ThreadStatus = true;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to terminate a thread in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131608/how-to-terminate-a-thread-in-c)

Comment: Killing the thread is never good option :)

Comment: ~@DmitryBychenko There is no change when I switch to `volatile`

Comment: *How* did you try to change the flag? BTW instead of using a flag that may or may not be changed by different threads, use a CancellationToken. It's built for *exactly* this purpose, and decouples your client code (the code that requests cancellation) from your class's internals

Comment: Why don't you use a timer? This way you won't block a thread only to wait for 2 seconds

Comment: Change `while (ThreadStatus)` to `while (volatile.Read(ref ThreadStatus))`. Do NOT change the field declaration to `volatile`. As Eric Lippert say: [`Frankly, I discourage you from ever making a volatile field.`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/06/16/atomicity-volatility-and-immutability-are-different-part-three/)

Comment: This code isn't compilable. Both `thread` and `processName` variables are unknown.

Comment: Can you please share your complete code including main? I'm unable to reproduce the issue. For me it just works.

Answer (score 2):

Use Cancellation token on Task instead of aborting thread. ref : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score -1):

`ThreadStatus` should be `volatile`:

`public volatile bool ThreadStatus = true;`

> The volatile keyword alerts the compiler that multiple threads will access the `ThreadStatus` data member, and therefore it should not make any optimization assumptions about the state of this member.

[More on `volatile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7.aspx)

Comment: This was mentioned in the comments, and OP already responded it does not fix the issue