# c# Stop Thread with a button click

Tags: c#, multithreading

How can I end my thread with a button click? I start my thread with a button click.

```
new Thread(SampleFunction).Start();
```

and my thread:

```
    void SampleFunction()
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            string Seconds = DateTime.Now.ToString("ss");
            if (Seconds == "00")
            {
                int i2 = i++;
                string myString = i2.ToString();
                AppendTextBox(myString);
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
            }                
        }
    }

    public void AppendTextBox(string value)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Action<string>(AppendTextBox), new object[] { value });
            return;
        }
        textBox4.Text += value;
    }
```

How do i cancel it? the following doesn't work:

```
private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     SampleFunction.Abort();
    }
```

Comment: Did you do any research at all like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131608/how-to-terminate-a-thread-in-c)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to terminate a thread in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131608/how-to-terminate-a-thread-in-c)

Comment: `while(true)` can certainly be approved.  But code like this shouldn't be written like this at all.  It has no benefit whatsoever over a System.Windows.Forms.Timer with an Interval of 2000.  Only disadvantages, rather major ones.  Even closing the form is already a major problem with a threading race that is quite hard to solve reliably.  That timer is quite easy to stop, use Stop().

Comment: Oops, "approved" = improved.

Comment: Please never call `Thread.Abort()`. Even if you handle any exceptions it can still corrupt the run-time meaning that the remaining threads may not function correctly. It should only be used when forcing an application to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SampleFunction` is a method, not a `Thread` object, so you can't call [`Abort()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.abort) like that.

You need to keep a reference to the `Thread`:

```
var thread = new Thread(SampleFunction);
thread.Start();
```

Then you can call `Abort()` when you want to kill it:

```
thread.Abort();
```

But keep in mind that it does *kill* it. The effect of `Abort()` is that it throws a `ThreadAbortException` in the thread. So it can stop at any moment and leave things in an unexpected state, so it may not be the best approach depending on what you're doing in the thread.

Here are a couple articles that discuss this and possibly better ways to stop a thread:

- [Destroying threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/destroying-threads)
- [Canceling threads cooperatively](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/canceling-threads-cooperatively)

Comment: thank you for your reply. -----        public void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var thread = new Thread(SampleFunction);
            thread.Start();
        }

        private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            thread.Abort();
        } ----------- I get error, thread doen't exist in a current content

Comment: Note to OP, that aborting a thread is usually always a bad idea and can be very dangerous.

Comment: I'm still unsure on how to stop my thread with a another button click

Comment: Just declare `thread` ( like `Thread thread;`) inside your class, but outside of any methods.

Comment: Please never call `Thread.Abort()`. Even if you handle any exceptions it can still corrupt the run-time meaning that the remaining threads may not function correctly. It should only be used when forcing an application to close.