# How to make a disable button to pause script

Tags: c#

Well, I made a script to just jump to work in several games, and I would like my program to have a button to activate and deactivate it so that it doesn't disturb me when I'm not playing (when minimizing the game), I managed to make the script run when I clicked on the activate button, but I don't have the slightest idea of how to put it to disable / pause on the "Desativar" button, and when I click again on "Activate" where it left off.
I'm going to apologize for my English if something is wrong

ps: I'm a newbie

Code:

```
 public partial class Pular : Form
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]

        static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(Keys vKey);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]

        static extern void mouse_event(int a, int b, int c, int d, int swed);

        int m3DOWN = 0x0020;
        int m3UP = 0x0040;

        public Pular()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            btnDesativar.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void Pular_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        void jump()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.Space) <0)
                {
                    mouse_event(m3DOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                    Thread.Sleep(9);
                    mouse_event(m3UP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                    Thread.Sleep(9);
                }
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
        }

        private void btnAtivar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnAtivar.Enabled = false;
            btnDesativar.Enabled = true;
            Thread jp = new Thread(jump) { IsBackground = true };
            jp.Start();
        }

        private void btnDesativar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnDesativar.Enabled = false;
            btnAtivar.Enabled = true;
            
        }
```

Comment: [c# Stop Thread with a button click](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53462988)

Comment: I'm trying to put the pause function on btnDesativar_Click, how do I do?

Comment: you need to pause the thread. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/pausing-and-resuming-threads An obvious but easily solved problem in your current code is that your thread is only local to your btnAtivar_Click method, but you could easily make it a private field in the class so that it can be accessed in other methods too.

Comment: But does it already have a "class" up there, or has nothing to do? And like I said, I'm a newbie, I didn't get it right