# how to close the serial port safely in c#

Tags: c#

I am developing windows forms application. I am communicating with serial port using separate thread. On button click I am closing the serial port and aborting the thread using `Thread.Abort()`.But I am getting

> Thread was being aborted exception.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Thread1.Abort(); 
   if (isPortOpened)
   {                
      serialPort1.DataReceived -= DataReceivedHandler;
      serialPort1.Close();                
   }
}
```

Comment: Do the closing in a `finally` block

Comment: `Thread.Abort` is being explicitly called. What do you expect? You should [***never, ever, ever, ever*** call `Thread.Abort`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632149/question-about-terminating-a-thread-cleanly-in-net). Really. You should signal to the thread to finish, and then call `Thread1.Join` to wait until it finishes gracefully.

Comment: Try removing the following line: `Thread1.Abort();`. Once removed, never put back in.

Comment: DataReceived event is already called on separate background thread. What is the purpose of your separate thread exactly?

Comment: @spender: I tried your suggestion and is working fine. Using a flag, I send signal to the thread to finish indirectly.Thanks a lot.

Comment: @spender ... I would add ... never use `Thread` if you don't have to ... better use `Task`s

Comment: @sowjanyaattaluri : Great. Thread.Abort is evil! I wrapped my comment into an answer for you to accept.

Comment: @Carsten AFAIK There are no Task based methods on SerialPort. It's a funny one. OP might be able to operate on SerialPort.BaseStream instead, but it would be a big deviation from current architecture.

Comment: ... are there `Thread` based ones? but never mind

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Thread.Abort` is being explicitly called. What do you expect?

You should [never, ever, ever, ever call Thread.Abort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632149/question-about-terminating-a-thread-cleanly-in-net). Really.

You should signal to the thread to finish, and then call `Thread1.Join` to wait until it finishes gracefully