# Is there a way to know if a thread is being aborted because the program is terminating?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Is there an event that will tell me whether a currently running thread is being aborted mid-way not because the user called `Abort` but because the program is terminating?

I need this for every thread shutting down along with information about the thread Id.

I was hoping it will be the `AppDomainUnload` event but [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h339syd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says nilch about it.

[This page on the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h339syd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says:

*When the runtime stops a background thread because the process is shutting down, no exception is thrown in the thread. However, when threads are stopped because the AppDomain.Unload method unloads the application domain, a ThreadAbortException is thrown in both foreground and background threads.*

To test the fact, I wrote this little program that spawns two long-running threads, one of which is a foreground thread while the other a background thread, and immediately proceeds to exit the current process, thereby attempting to unload the current appdomain.

This should have called not only the `DomainUnload` handler but also attempted to abort the two running threads and sent them a `ThreadAbortException`.

But none of that happens.

The **Output** window displays the following output:

```
[#10] [Foreground]Starting to do stuff.
The thread 0x183c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
[#9] [Worker]Starting to do stuff.
[#10] [Foreground]Slept for 5 seconds. Now finishing up the doing of stuff.
The thread 0x2954 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[11224] KnowAboutDyingThread.vshost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace KnowAboutDyingThread
{
    // Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h339syd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
    // When the runtime stops a background thread because the process is shutting down, 
    // no exception is thrown in the thread. However, when threads are stopped because the 
    // AppDomain.Unload method unloads the application domain, a ThreadAbortException is 
    // thrown in both foreground and background threads.

    // I am trying that out
    // I asked a question here about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37552668/is-there-a-way-to-know-if-a-thread-is-being-aborted-because-the-program-is-termi
    // Permalink: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37552668/303685

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DomainUnload += CurrentDomain_DomainUnload;
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Do);
            var t = new Thread(Do);
            t.Name = "Foreground";
            t.Start();

            Process.GetCurrentProcess().Close();
        }

        private static void CurrentDomain_DomainUnload(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.Print("Unloading current appdomain...");
        }

        static void Do(object state)
        {
            try
            {
                Debug.Print(string.Format($"[#{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}] [{Thread.CurrentThread.Name ?? "Worker"}]Starting to do stuff."));
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                Debug.Print(string.Format($"[#{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}] [{Thread.CurrentThread.Name ?? "Worker"}]Slept for 5 seconds. Now finishing up the doing of stuff."));
            }
            catch(ThreadAbortException abort)
            {
                Debug.Print(string.Format($"[#{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}] [{Thread.CurrentThread.Name ?? "Worker"}]Do got ThreadAbortException: {abort.GetType().Name}: {abort.Message}"));
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.Print(string.Format($"[#{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}] [{Thread.CurrentThread.Name ?? "Worker"}]Do had an exception: {ex.GetType().Name}: {ex.Message}"));
            }
        }
    }
}





  [1]: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.domainunload%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
```

Comment: Don't `Thread.Abort`. Whatever you're using it for, you're taking the wrong approach. `Thread.Abort` is evil. You should be asking "how do I terminate my program without calling `Thread.Abort`". Once again, [`Thread.Abort` is evil.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632149/question-about-terminating-a-thread-cleanly-in-net)

Comment: I am well aware of the ills of using `Thread.Abort` and of `Thread.Interrupt` and my question has little to do with the side-effects of using those methods.

Comment: I think you need to do `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();` to get the behavior you want. doing `Close()` triggers a graceful shutdown, but the `Do` on the forground thread does not have any way to monitor for the close message so will not trigger the process. And even then, `DomainUnload` still might not fire due to it being forcefully terminated, but at least you might not get the "Now finishing...." section.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thank you. I tried calling `Kill` but that doesn't help either. It just terminates abruptly without printing anything at all. I did a `Thread.Sleep(1500)` on the `Main` thread but that only allows for the 2 spawned threads to begin. Importantly, none of the clean-up code is executed.

Comment: To communicate with the thread you need to use a stream (some times called a pipe) or a semaphore (like WaitOne).  Using Standard Input/Output like Scott recommended is one type of stream, but there are other way of accomplishing the same.  You may want to read following article from msdn : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686358(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @jdweng Thank you. I will go through the documentation for unmanaged threading once I have gone through the managed one. I am doing a second round of reading of Managed Threading, this time summarizing my thoughts, taking notes and trying out code samples. Once done, I will go through that link you have shared. Many thanks.

Comment: I try to avoid timers and do everything using Events similar to how a Form project works.  A form project uses button clicks and and mouse clicks.  A Background worker class stays open so you can call do work as often as you like.  I also like passing a STATE object to the BackGroundWorker like a parameter list.  See following example : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt679044.aspx

Comment: As asked, this question is fairly broad. It's not really clear what answer would address your specific concern. As the documentation explains, `DomainUnload` is not raised in the default domain, so the code example you posted isn't relevant at all. It's by design that the event isn't raised in that example. _Maybe_ what you want is to execute code in a different domain, where the event would be raised; but you might have to unload the domain explicitly to get the event to be raised. Ultimately, if Windows kills a process, the threads in the process aren't going to know about it. They just die.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thank you for your remarks. I found them useful. I will get at this after a few hours of sleep and post back an update.

Answer (score 0):

Background threads are not supposed to be gracefully terminated.

You will not be able to catch any async exceptions. This holds for foreground threads too.

In a foreground thread, you will be able to gracefully get into a `finally` block, but not the catch blocks.

The simplest thing you can do is probably using finalized objects:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace ReliableStop
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("-- Started Main. Thread: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

            var everStarted = new ManualResetEvent(false);

            var t = new Thread(o =>
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("-- Thread entered here.");
                everStarted.Set();

                using (new PostMortemThreadDump())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(100);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("-- Attempt to catch everything.");
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("-- Attempt to process finally.");
                    }                    
                }
            });
            t.IsBackground = true;
            t.Start();

            // Check that the thread has started.
            everStarted.WaitOne();

            // ... Good bye, no need to kill, I will die on my own.
        }
    }

    class PostMortemThreadDump : IDisposable
    {
        int threadId { get; }
        public PostMortemThreadDump()
        {
            threadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        }

        ~PostMortemThreadDump()
        {
            Dispose(false);
        }

        void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("-- PostMortemThreadDump. Finished normally.");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("-- PostMortemThreadDump. Thread: {0}", threadId);
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
-- Started Main. Thread: 9
-- Thread entered here.
The thread 0x6fc8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x12b4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
-- PostMortemThreadDump. Thread: 10
The program '[25260] ReliableStop.vshost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Now, if you change to using a foreground thread you also get the `finally block executed:

```
-- Started Main. Thread: 9
-- Thread entered here.
The thread 0x4d54 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x20c8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
-- Attempt to process finally.
-- PostMortemThreadDump. Finished normally.
The thread 0x6928 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[26328] ReliableStop.vshost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

As you can see, the finalizer runs in both cases, and in a foreground thread, you get the `finally` blocks executed.

Calling `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Close()` does not affect this scenario.