# Configure a timeout in web.config for a web service

Tags: c#, iis

I have a web service hosted in IIS 7.5.
The web service works fine.
I try to configure a timeout in the web.config, but I can't do it.
I tried in my web.config :

```
<Configuration>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.8" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8" executionTimeout="10" /> <!-- 10 seconds -->
<sessionState timeout="2" /> <!-- 2 minutes -->
</system.web>
</Configuration>
```

and in the web service controller :

```
Thread.Sleep(180000) //3 minutes
```

I thought the execution would stop after 10 seconds but instead it stops after 1 minute, whatever I put in the "executionTimeout" and "timeout" parameters.
I have searched in IIS but impossible to find what this minute corresponds to.

Does someone have an idea ?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/39153780/6527049

Comment: what kind of webservice is this? is it a wcf one? webapi? something else?

Comment: First question: Is this a web service built on top of the ASP.NET MVC WebAPI or the old school ASP.NET SOAP webservices infrastructure?

Comment: Second question: is this an asynchronous endpoint?

Comment: Thanks for your posts. vivek nuna : I tried to set the timeout in IIS as you proposed but it's still the same. rene, Kev : my Web service is a REST Web service written in C#, it's not MVC nor SOAP.

Comment: This not an asynchronous endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

IIS timeout or httpruntime execution timeout won' t be able to kill a sleeping thread.

As you can see, thread sleep won't be limited by IIS

[image]

To make execution timeout work, you need to do actural process instead of  a thread sleep.

So if you need to achieve this, please try something like this in your code.

```
thread.Start();
            thread.Join(1500);
            thread.Abort();
```

Or use `CancellationTokenSource()` and `CancelAfter(10000)`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/cancel-async-tasks-after-a-period-of-time

Answer (score 0):

Jokies Ding :
Thanks for the CancellationToken.
You showed me the way.
And thanks to this link :
[How to stop a thread if thread takes too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42268735/how-to-stop-a-thread-if-thread-takes-too-long)
I use tasks which are more clean than raw threads.