# Exception while stopping a running thread in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception

I have a thread in my application named "FirstThread" which is running in the background. While trying to stop this running thread using "FirstThread.Abort() " it returns an exception.Can you suggest any solutions for this

```
 if (FirstThread.ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.Running)
     FirstThread.Abort();
```

[image]

Comment: `Thread.Abort()` is evil and should **never** be used. https://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2004/11/12/cancellation

Comment: ok.Then How can I stop the thread

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. 

We're going to struggle if you don't specify what the exception is. Additionally a piece of code to demonstrate what is going on would be very helpful.

Comment: Would this be a **ThreadAbortException** by any chance? That's how `Thread.Abort()` works - and is also one of the reasons why it's not at all recommended.

Comment: `Then How can I stop the thread `  Read the link that @Spender provided; it's very useful, athough a bit old. Better nowadays to use [`Task` and task cancellation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-cancellation).

Comment: Please take the time to read the [tour] and [ask]. Please don't post exceptions as images (and you posted the most irrelevant part of the stack trace). Please show the _relevant_ code, the exception _type_, _message_ and stack trace.

Comment: Aborting threads can leave the run-time in a corrupted state. You can't trust your program to run correctly after aborting threads. You should only do so if you are trying to forcibly exit your app.

Comment: Check this [relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3632149/1997232).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Usually to avoid these exceptions I use flags. You can create a flag called `stopFirstThread` and rather than abort the thread you set flag value to `True`, and inside first thread keep checking for this flag, when it become `True` you can end thread peacefully.